# [Auto Select Text Between two given words in a notepad++]

Tags: regex, notepad++, notepad, programmers-notepad

I have a large text files.I have a given specific keyword [with spaces in between like "ABC DEF G"].
It either occurs in the text file exactly two times or does not occur at all.

I want to have a notepad++ search such that all the text between these two keywords (around 300 to 1000 lines) gets selected automatically.
I will then do some operation on this selected text via my plugin.So my first question is:

Is this autos-election possible(via regular expression or some already built plugin).

If yes ,can some one please suggest.

As of now I am reading entire text file to search which is time and memory consuming.
Thanks.

Comment: You mean like [THIS](https://ibb.co/dovFiw)?

Comment: yes exactly like this :)

Comment: Great. I have added it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this Regex:

`(?<=ABC DEF G)[\s\S]*(?=ABC DEF G)`

[Click for Demo](https://regex101.com/r/8cOYW8/1)

**Explanation:**

- `(?<=ABC DEF G)` - [Positive Lookbehind](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to find the position which is preceded by the text `ABC DEF G`
- `[\s\S]*` - matches 0+ occurrences of any character
- `(?=ABC DEF G)` - [Positive lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to find the position immediately followed by the text `ABC DEF G`

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: just one thing if you can help me. Text is like ABC DEF G *****.then some text . Then ABC DEF G ******.I want the text from next line after ***** and till i reach A again in the second. Further if the text is not present ,what will this expression do.First problem I can also work around by doing character scanning which I am already doing in my plugin.Can you tell about what happens if this text is not present.

Comment: @NikhilSaxena Try this for that case: `(?<=ABC DEF G)[^\n]*\n\K[\s\S]*(?=ABC DEF G)`. See [HERE](https://regex101.com/r/8cOYW8/2). You are selecting from next line onwards.

Comment: It is working correct.But in some cases ,it is not working.When it is not working,text files are large around 4 lac lines,In case of small files upto 2.5 lac ,it is working.Does this search may fail according to file size or it may be some other reason?

Comment: Well it shouldn't. Since we are dealing with huge files, may be for some files, it is taking a bit longer. To reduce the number of steps, try using this one `ABC DEF G[^\n]*\n\K[\s\S]*(?=ABC DEF G)`. I have removed the Positive lookbehind part for a faster match.

Comment: :Just one last requirement.It is also selecting one new line character extra.Can i skip selecting that new line character.It is affecting decoding of selected text.